# How to put a link to a website in Windows Xp Welcome Screen

Tags: c#, registry

How can I put a shortcut to run iexplore.exe and go to a specific site in the windows welcome screen (log in screen). 
For example: a software called fim edits the welcome screen to add their own shortcut to their application.

Another example of a software that edits the welcome screen is here:
http://www.rohos.com/support/knowledge-base/windows-logon-with-yubikey/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first quick hint: This could be achived by replacing c:\windows\system32\logonui.exe with a custom exe. The question ist what the requirements for this exe are. I'd be interested as well. **[Edit:]** There is a tool called "Resource Hacker" that lets you change program resources up to Windows XP